# bashscript for hive queries giving errors

Tags: sql, bash, hive

I am trying to execute a bashcript containing hive queries. But, when i execute the script it shows that `raw_data` and `central` table not found. I already have these tables in hive. Below, is the bash script. Kindly suggest what's wrong.

```
#!/bin/bash
hive -e 
        "CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION rowSequence AS 'com.hive.udf.UDFRowSequence'; "
hive -e "
        create table staging (id String,speed String,time String,time_id int);"
hive -e "
        insert into table staging select marker.marker.id,
     marker.marker.speed ,
     marker.marker.time as time,
     rowSequence() as time_id
     from raw_data
     lateral view explode (raw_data.markers.marker)marker as marker;"
hive -e "
        create table processed (plc string,direction string,table int,speed string,time_id string,day int);"
hive -e "
        insert into table processed select c.plc,c.direction,c.table,t.speed as speed,t.time_id,0 from central c JOIN staging t ON (t.id = c.boxno);"
```

Comment: You will have more luck if you posted the output when running the script as well.

Comment: The output said that "central table does not exist" and "raw_data table does not exist"

Answer (score 0):

Include **use [databasename]**

Eg..

> hive -e "use dummy_database;create table staging (id String,speed
>   String,time String,time_id int);"
>
> hive -e "use dummy_database;insert into table staging select
>   marker.marker.id,
>            marker.marker.speed ,
>        marker.marker.time as time,
>        rowSequence() as time_id
>        from raw_data
>        lateral view explode (raw_data.markers.marker)marker as marker;"